# device to measure vibration - retrieving data?

Tags: device, concept

hey guys,
i'm working on a concept for university. i wonder what's the easiest and best way to measure certain vibration in a room. imagine a room full o people dancing. is there any affordable device i can put on the floor that sends data to my computer so i can read out vibration values or use vibration as data?

thank you for your help

Comment: How about something like a contact microphone?

Comment: A seismometer might work too.. My high school had one in a classroom; we had to relocate it because it was picking up vibrations from the students.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that a microphone, as [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) suggested, would work, but if you're on a near-zero budget, find an old speaker and bolt it face-down to the floor. Connect the wires to a 1/8" phono plug and plug it into the microphone-in jack on your sound card. Record the vibration data using Audacity. The floor's vibration will flex the speaker cone and generate small amounts of electricity, which the sound card input will see. If you put a foam-lined box over the top (actually back) of the speaker you'll minimize the effect of sound waves from the air on the speaker cone.

Answer (score 1):

There is specific noise monitoring equipment which could serve that purpose, depending on how accurate the information you are monitoring needs to be.

I used to operate sound monitoring equipment as part of a rotating equipment inspection program when I was in the Navy.  Basically it was a set of transducers you mounted to the equipment you wanted to monitor, and a proprietary box for recording and analyzing the results.  I'm sure you could easily replicate that functionality with a PC.

Do a search for "Vibration Monitoring Equipment" or "Condition Monitoring" and see what turns up.  If you are at a University with an engineering department I would imagine the ME's would have something like what you're looking for.